# Can a 4 wire dimmer lamp be installed with 3 wires?

Tags: electrical, lighting, dimmer-switch, lamp

I'm sorry about not knowing the terminology/what exactly is going on but our maintenance worker told us we can't install our ceiling lamp with a dimmer switch and I just wanted to check on here to see if we should call in a seperate electrician before we give up.
So the issue is that our old lamp/switch had 3 wires and the new one requires 4 to connect. Maintenance worker said that we would have to tear open the wall and rewire it if we wanted the lamp to have a dimmer. Attached is a page from the manual of the new lamp as well as pictures of the ceiling and current dimmer switch. Thank you. We are located in Europe (in case that makes a difference).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Europe" is a mighty big place, please [edit] to be a bit more specific. ;)  Also, if you're renting, there's a significant chance that your rental agreement won't allow you to call in your own electrician. This may also be the case in a multi-family dwelling, even if you own your own flat. Make sure you check your property documents to ensure you _can_ call your own electrician.

Comment: Is it the lamp or the dimmer being changed?  If the dimmer, I suggest looking for a three wire dimmer(if they exist in your region).

Answer (score 1):

The wiring diagram you show in the 3rd pic seems to show a lamp which has an 'extra' pair of wires for dimming control.
This is unusual (although not unheard of) and would require a compatible (also unusual) dimmer.
It also requires (as can be seen in the diagram) 4 wires between the lamp and dimmer as opposed to the much more common 3 wires.
So your building maintenance worker is correct - if you're set on using that particular lamp, and you want to be able to dim it, you need an extra wire. You also need a compatible (non-standard) dimmer to put the dimming control signal onto that extra wire.

With only 3 wires, you won't be able to dim this lamp (only turn it on and off), and it's possible that trying to dim it with a standard dimmer would damage it.

Comment: Those are LED lights I take it? The wires do not look thick enough to handle mains voltage.

Comment: @DuncanC if the circular thing in the picture is the fixture, then almost certainly it's LED. It's too thin to likely be anything else.